# JS find an array's element is in another array or not

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JS and I want to check an array's element in another array or not, also want to add to the array if not exist.

Here has 2 arrays:

```
let array1 = [
    [1, 3, "Betty", "Betty@email.com"],
    [2, 5, "Mary", "Mary@email.com"],
    [3, 73, "Tom", "Tom@email.com"]
];
let array2 = [
    [1, 3, "Betty", "Betty@email.com"],
    [9, 25, "Jo", "Jo@email.com"],
    [10, 733, "Louis", "Louis@email.com"]
];
```

Then I want to check the every single element of array2 is in array1 or not, and checking by the name or mail address, also push it to array1 if not.

But I don't know what's the method to do it, please help. Many Thanks!!

Comment: are all the elements in the same order in all arrays? It seems like you might want to be using objects here.

Comment: Hi, What have you tried so far? Can you post minimal reproducible code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes all elements in same order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my version I first create a dictionary object `dict` that helps me find an existing element in `array1` and then I step through all the elements of `array2` and push them onto `array1` if the combination of both, name and mail address is not yet in `array1`.

```js
let array1 = [
    [1, 3, "Betty", "Betty@email.com"],
    [2, 5, "Mary", "Mary@email.com"],
    [3, 73, "Tom", "Tom@email.com"]
];
let array2 = [
    [1, 3, "Betty", "Betty@email.com"],
    [9, 25, "Jo", "Jo@email.com"],
    [10, 733, "Louis", "Louis@email.com"]
];

const dict=array1.reduce((a,c)=>
 (a[c.slice(2).join('|')]=1,a),{});

array2.forEach(c=>dict[c.slice(2).join('|')]||array1.push(c))

console.log(array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use this, but first understand what you are doing.

```
for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {

        // If name or email matches break
        if(array1[j][2] === array2[i][2] || array1[j][3] === array2[i][3]) {
            break;
        } else {
            // If it comes here than that means email or name does not match so pushing it
            if(j === array1.length - 1) { // Last Element
                array1.push(array2[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know where is the [i] come from?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I have created 2 function
The first one. This function will check if `data` is in `array` or not.
*Note: This function is work around only to this question (Array nested within array)*

```js
function isExistInArray(data, array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let isExist = true
    for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      if (data[j] !== array[i][j]) {
        isExist = false
      }
    }
    if (isExist) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

And the second one is function to add item in array2 into array1 if it isn't exist.

```js
function combineArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const result = [...arr1]
  arr2.forEach(item => {
    if (!isExistInArray(item, arr1)) {
      result.push(item)
    }
  })
  return result
}
```

And then this code is now working!
Here is full code

```js
let array1 = [[1, 3, 'Betty', 'Betty@email.com'], [2, 5, 'Mary', 'Mary@email.com'], [3, 73, 'Tom', 'Tom@email.com']]
let array2 = [[1, 3, 'Betty', 'Betty@email.com'], [9, 25, 'Jo', 'Jo@email.com'], [10, 733, 'Louis', 'Louis@email.com']]

function isExistInArray(data, array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let isExist = true
    for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      if (data[j] !== array[i][j]) {
        isExist = false
      }
    }
    if (isExist) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

function combineArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const result = [...arr1]
  arr2.forEach(item => {
    if (!isExistInArray(item, arr1)) {
      result.push(item)
    }
  })
  return result
}

console.log(combineArray(array1, array2))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Find variable is array or not**

```
const arr = [{name:'vishal'},{name:'Rahul'}];
if(Array.isArray(arr)){
console.log("array")
}
else{
console.log('not array');
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.